# BooleanField not showing the selected value on Update

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In a model I have defined the following field:

```
manager = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_TYPE_CHOICES, default=BOOL_TYPE_NO)
```

forms:

```
'manager': RadioSelectWidget(choices=BOOL_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

const

```
BOOL_TYPE_NO = 0
BOOL_TYPE_YES = 1

BOOL_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (BOOL_TYPE_NO, 'No'),
    (BOOL_TYPE_YES, 'Yes')
)
```

widget:

```
class RadioSelectWidget(forms.RadioSelect):
  template_name = 'widgets/radio-select.html'
```

--

```
{% with id=widget.attrs.id %}
    <ul{% if id %} id="{{ id }}"{% endif %} class="list--inline list--reset">
        {% for group, options, index in widget.optgroups %}
            {% if group %}
                <li class="list__item">{{ group }}
                <ul{% if id %} id="{{ id }}_{{ index }}"{% endif %} class="list--inline list--reset">
            {% endif %}
        {% for option in options %}
            <li class="list__item">{% include option.template_name with widget=option %}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if group %}</ul></li>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endwith %}
```

I use a custom widget just to add some classes to the Django html.

The problem is not the widget, because I use the same widget in combination with SmallInteger an there are no issues.

But with Boolean, one update, no option is selected, on create is ok, the default one is selected.

Comment: What are `BOOL_TYPE_CHOICES ` and `BOOL_TYPE_NO`, and your template `'widgets/radio-select.html'`?

Comment: @Alasdair update, is just django default plus some clases

Comment: Have you tried using `True` and `False` instead of `0` and `1`?